# The existence of a discrete subset of a metric space whose power set is contained in the Borel sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, large-cardinals

Assume we work under ZFC.
Let $(\mathcal X,\rho)$ be a metric space equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr B$ (i.e., the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets in $(\mathcal X,\rho)$).
Let $$\delta_{\mathcal X} = \sup_{A\subseteq\mathcal X}\{|A|: \text{$A$ is discrete}\}.$$

Assume $\delta_{\mathcal X}\geq \kappa$ where $\kappa$ is a real-valued measurable cardinal.
What are necessary / sufficient conditions under which there exists a discrete subset $D\in\mathscr B$ with $|D|=\kappa$?

(As noted below, since $D$ is discrete, one has $2^D\subseteq\mathscr B$ as well.)

Comment: To apply Zorn's Lemma, would I not need to know the (false) proposition that a union of a chain of discrete sets is discrete?

Comment: Thank you GEdgar for the comment. I see my mistake. It can well be that the supremum is not achieved by a discrete subset. I edited the question. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

**not yet an answer**
If $A \subseteq X$ then
$$
\text{Borel}(A) = \{ A \cap E : E \in \text{Borel}(X)\} .
$$

If $A$ is discrete, then $\text{Borel}(A) = 2^A$.

So: if  $A \subseteq X$ is discrete, then $2^A \subseteq \text{Borel}(X)$ is equlivalent to $A \in \text{Borel}(X)$.

Then the question becomes: is there a discrete  $A \in \text{Borel}(X)$ with $|A| = \kappa$?